# Track count of Printing Pages in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, count

I am creating a set-up for window service in WPF. The service is always running in my system. I want to get the count of printing pages. If I am going to take print any documents like doc, PDF, excel from my computer, the service will get automatically count of printing pages and current date-time. Then it will create the log for it. How to get the count of Printing pages using C# coding in WPF.

Answer (score 3):

This probably might help you to get the count of Prints Taken

```
try
{
    string PrinterJobs = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob";
    ManagementObjectSearcher FindPrintJobs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(PrinterJobs);
    ManagementObjectCollection prntJobCollection = FindPrintJobs.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection)
    {
        string jobName = prntJob.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        string documentName = prntJob.Properties["Document"].Value.ToString();
        string nbcopie = prntJob.Properties["TotalPages"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

You can also do have a look on [PrintMonitor – A C# print spooler monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2009/08/05/printmonitor-a-c-print-spooler-monitor.aspx)

**Edit**

Just Applied `IList<ManagementBaseObject>` to get the list of all the network printers installed on ur PC. As suggested in your comment.

```
try
{
    IList<ManagementBaseObject> printers = new List<ManagementBaseObject>();
    string PrinterJobs = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob";
    ManagementObjectSearcher FindPrintJobs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(PrinterJobs);
    ManagementObjectCollection prntJobCollection = FindPrintJobs.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection)
    {
        if ((bool)printer["Network"]) 
        {
            printers.Add(printer);
        }
        string jobName = prntJob.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        string documentName = prntJob.Properties["Document"].Value.ToString();
        string nbcopie = prntJob.Properties["TotalPages"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. That coding is working fine but I can't get the shared printer. I configured shared printer. That printer only doesn't get others are Fax, Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Send to One-note. These things only got.

Comment: @Lawrence: Have a look on the edit. Since I understood only half part of ur comments thus I made my changes. See if it helps